# JSON to Interface[]

Tags: typescript

i load a JSON file into an interface array

```
[
    {
      "id":1,
      "attributes":{
        "name":"a name",
        "description":"a description",
      }
    },
    {
      "id":1,
      "attributes":{
        "name":"a name",
        "description":"a description",
      }
    }
]

export interface MyInterface {
    name:string,
    description:string
}

this.data_ : MyInterface[]=[]

this.data_ = (jsondata as any).default.map(ji => ji.attributes);
```

It works fine but now i'd like to add the id in the interface

```
export interface MyInterface {
    id:number,
    name:string,
    description:string
}
```

and i can't figure how to deal with the map function in that case. Is there a kind of "..." operator?
Thank you by advance

Comment: Your interface is wrong, it should be `export interface MyInterface {
    id:number,
    attributes: {
        name:string,
        description:string
    }
}`

Comment: no my interface is not "wrong", it describes the data i want to have. It should not depend on how the data is stored. This is why i use a map function

Comment: Oh, I have misunderstood. Then something like this should work: `.map(ji => ({id: ji.id, ...ji.attributes}));` or the other way around, depending on which id property you want to be overriden, if 2 exist: `.map(ji => ({...ji.attributes, id: ji.id}));`

Comment: I tried that already, it dont work :)

Comment: I mean I just tried it and it does work.

Comment: i see, i did try .map(ji => {...ji.attributes, id: ji.id}), which missed a couple of ()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return an object with the attributes and add the id manually when mapping
over data

```
 this.data_ = (jsondata as any).default.map(ji => {

   return {id: ji.id , ...ji.attributes} 

 });
```